# Is it ok to extract repeating assertions to a private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-duplication

I have been writing tests for a class, all of which look something like this:

```
expectedResult = ....;
exception = new ....;
mock.Setup(sameexpression).Throws(exception);
result = sameObject.SameMethodToTest();
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, result);
```

I was wondering if it would be considered bad style to extract this code (including the common assertions) into a shared private method, that would receive the expectedResult and the exception as parameters, and thus would reduce code duplication and maintenance.

Comment: For me it sounds like you're asserting same things in multiple test methods. But why would you even test same thing multiple times?

Comment: The tests differ, the expectedResult and the exception are different for every test... I prepared it over looping over multiple values in just one test method

Comment: This appears to be opinion based, but if you take a look at some tests for something complicated (like the C# compiler), then you will see that the setup / test code has been abstracted: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Emit/CodeGen/SwitchTests.cs

Answer (score 3):

I'd keep it in the test. The problem with extracting the code is it makes it harder to identify what is being tested. And, if you need to make a functionality change, updating shared code in a test is more difficult than updating code only used in that specific test.

Comment: That is also my personal opinion - try to keep the tests self maintained. Once you have you production code under test you can always refactor it so that you don't have to write these kinds of tests (since they are bugging you)